# Can't set the number of ticks on time-based x-axis to custom amount for bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, axis-labels

I'm currently using the following code to set the number of ticks on my time-based x-axis to 5; however, every single tick continues to display regardless of what number I insert within "ticks()".

**The code I'm using to set the number of ticks to 5**

```
let xAxisLower = d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m-%d"))
        .tickPadding(15);
```

How do I set the number of ticks on the x-axis to 5 and why can't I do so with .ticks(5)?

**The JavaScript code (refer to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phao5814/61xubw65/6/) for further detail)**

```
tradeArr = [
    {date: "2017-06-15" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-14" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-13" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-12" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-09" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-08" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-07" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-06" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-05" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-02" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-06-01" , bps: 13.9},
    {date: "2017-05-31" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-30" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-29" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-26" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-25" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-24" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-23" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-22" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-19" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-18" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-17" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-16" , bps: 1.95},
    {date: "2017-05-15" , bps: 0},
    {date: "2017-05-12" , bps: 0}
];

tradeArr.forEach(obj => {
    obj.date = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(obj.date);
})

generateBarChart(tradeArr);

function generateBarChart(data) {
    console.log(data);

    // chart configuration
    let margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
    };

    let width;
    let height;

    let x = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));

    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.bps; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.bps; })])

    let xAxisLower = d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m-%d"))
        .tickPadding(15);

    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(2)
        .tickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(15);

    let svg = d3
        .select("#price-chart-graph")
            .style("position", "relative") // strictly for the tooltip
        .append("svg") // append an svg to the div
            .style("overflow", "hidden")
            .style("position", "relative");

    let artboard = svg
                    .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.right + ")");

    let xAxisLowerEl = artboard.append("g") // x-axis
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .style("font-size", "14px");

    let yAxisEl = artboard.append("g") // y-axis
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .style("font-size", "14px");

    let bars = artboard.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .style("fill", "black")

    function drawChart() {
        width = parseInt(d3.select("#price-chart-graph").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right;
        height = parseInt(d3.select("#price-chart-graph").style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right) // give it width
        svg.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom) // give it height

        x.rangeRound([0, width], .05).padding(0.1);
        y.range([height, 0]);
        // call new x axis
        xAxisLowerEl.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxisLower);
        yAxisEl.call(yAxis);

        bars
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return x.bandwidth()})
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.bps); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.bps); })

    }

    drawChart();

    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your x-axis is of type `scaleBand`, and `ticks()` doesn't work on banded axes. From the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_ticks):

> This method has no effect if the scale does not implement scale.ticks,
>   as with band and point scales

You can however explicitly set the values with `tickValues()`, so you can try filtering the domain down to five values and setting manually. This may get you in the right direction:

```
let tickInterval = 5;
let tickValues = data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }).filter(function(d, i) { return i % tickInterval === 0 });
let xAxisLower = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m-%d"))
    .tickValues(tickValues)
    .tickPadding(15);
```

You might need to tweak `tickInterval` to fit the length of your data, but that should be a start.